# Extract the superclass of a owl:unionOf list

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

Is it possible to get the superclass of a owl:unionOf list? I have something like the following:

```
ex:A rdf:type owl:Class ;
     owl:unionOf (ex:pet ex:animal1 ) .

ex:B rdf:type owl:Class ;
     owl:unionOf (ex:pet ex:animal2) .
```

What I'm trying to do is something simple like this:

```sql
    SELECT ?x WHERE {
      ?x superclass ex:pet
    }
```

where the results should be **ex:A** and **ex:B**. If **ex:pet** were replaced by **ex:animal1**, then the result would be just **ex:A**.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking.  When you say that x is an "A union B", you're saying that x is either an A or a B (or both).

Comment: doesn't  A owl:unionOf (B C) implie that B and C are subclasses of A? So when I add a new class to my ontology, would be nice to say it is an union of different existing classes, instead of editing all the exisiting classes and say now they are a subclass of the new class. But what I need to do is a query when I have B to get A. Sorry for all the missunderstandings..quite new to alle the ontology stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship should be the other way around: if your sparql endpoint supports inferences, then

```
SELECT ?x 
WHERE
{ex:pet subClassOf ?x.
};
```

should work.

Comment: I'm using Jena to do the queries, seems like it doesn't 'understand' that there are subclasses when I define it with unionOf..

Comment: That means there is no reasoning profile set up for the SPARQL endpoint you're using. If you cannot switch it to use reasoning, you'll have to make the SPARQL query more complex because it will have to include the structure of the unionOf in its clauses.

Comment: Thank you! That put me in the right direction. Just had to add the OWLReasoner. One more question though, do you know how I can filter out owl:Thing, rdfs:Resource and the own class in the result?  Also I want to get only the direct superclass, not the subclasses of the subclass and so on.

Comment: If you're using OWLReasoner, the methods have a boolean flag for direct and indirect relations. Set it to true for direct only